# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.wicket.MetaDataKey: method <init>()V not found

Tags: java, spring, jetty, tomcat7, wicket

Help, I have problem on Spring.4 + wicket.6 and jetty / tomcat 7.

The project compiles correctly locally, while on jetty / tomcat returns this error ..

```
 21407 [main] WARN org.mortbay.log - failed wicket.revman: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.wicket.MetaDataKey: method <init>()V not found
    21407 [main] WARN org.mortbay.log - failed org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext@2384fd7a{/tm,/opt/jetty/webapps/tm.war}: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.wicket.MetaDataKey: method <init>()V not found
    21683 [main] WARN org.mortbay.log - failed ContextHandlerCollection@229e571f: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.wicket.MetaDataKey: method <init>()V not found
    21685 [main] INFO org.mortbay.log - Opened /opt/jetty/logs/request.2014_05_28.log
    21685 [main] WARN org.mortbay.log - failed HandlerCollection@28c0945b: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.wicket.MetaDataKey: method <init>()V not found
    21685 [main] ERROR org.mortbay.log - Error starting handlers
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.wicket.MetaDataKey: method <init>()V not found
        at org.apache.wicket.authroles.authorization.strategies.role.metadata.MetaDataRoleAuthorizationStrategy$1.<init>(MetaDataRoleAuthorizationStrategy.java:61)
        at org.apache.wicket.authroles.authorization.strategies.role.metadata.MetaDataRoleAuthorizationStrategy.<clinit>(MetaDataRoleAuthorizationStrategy.java:60)
        at org.apache.wicket.authroles.authorization.strategies.role.RoleAuthorizationStrategy.<init>(RoleAuthorizationStrategy.java:40)
        at org.apache.wicket.authroles.authentication.AuthenticatedWebApplication.init(AuthenticatedWebApplication.java:69)
        at com.gc.mf.revman.web.WicketApplication.init(WicketApplication.java:68)
        at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.init(WicketFilter.java:570)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doStart(FilterHolder.java:97)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:713)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1282)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:518)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:499)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:156)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
        at org.mortbay.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:985)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.mortbay.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:194)
        at org.mortbay.start.Main.start(Main.java:534)
        at org.mortbay.start.Main.start(Main.java:441)
        at org.mortbay.start.Main.main(Main.java:119)
```

on tomcat 8 is Perfect.

Please Help Me...

Comment: Did you check this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9125704/exception-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-apache-wicket-attributemodifier-appen

Comment: Where's the code in question?